# Show a code is cyclic given the generator matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclic-groups, coding-theory

I am given $\mathcal{C}$ the following code over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with generator matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and I have to decide whether or not the following code is cyclic. I don't have the solution, so I need a check on my procedure

---

My attempt:

Let  $c=(c_1,ldots,c_6$ a word in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $c = [a_1,a_2,a_3] G$, so I have $$c = (a_2,a_1,a_3,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3,a_2+a_3)$$

If I consider the *shift of one position*, I obtain
$$c[1] = (a_2 + a_3,a_2,a_1,a_3,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3)$$

and I have to see if this word is in $\mathcal{C}$. So, I want to determine if there exists $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ such that $$c[1] = b_1 r_1 + b_2 r_2 + b_3 r_3 = (b_2,b_1,b_3,b_1+b_2,b_1+b_3,b_2+b_3)$$

Hence, I find

$\begin{cases}
b_1 = a_2 \\
b_3 = a_1 \\
b_1 + b_2 = a_3 \\
\end{cases}$

from which I determine  $b_2 = a_3+ a_2$

**But**, for instance $$b_2 +b_3 = a_3 +a_2 + a_1 \ne a_1+a_3$$

and so since this condition is not fulfilled, it's not cyclic.

Is eveytihng right?

Comment: For _this_ question, it might be easier to just calculate the eight codewords and check if the code is cyclic.

Comment: Yeah sure, but I was looknig for a check on the procedure actually :) @DilipSarwate